# binary file and interpretation in java script?

Tags: binaryfiles, interpretation

### Can we write source code in *binary file* when we are using *interpretation* or not?

Can we write source code in binary file when we are using interpretation or not?

Can we write source code in binary file when we are using interpretation or not?

Can we write source code in binary file when we are using interpretation or not?

Can we write source code in binary file when we are using interpretation or not?

Comment: Why would you want to?